# How to trigger ChartJS legend onClick with out interrupting its normal working

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When legends in the chart.js pie (v2.5.0) chart is click I want to log which legend is being clicked. For that I add an onClick function to the legend and call default function  Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick in it. but it's getting errored and the chart is not updated.

This is the configuration I have used

```
"legend": {
    "position": "top",
    "onClick": function(e,l){
            console.log("l.text");
            Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick.call(this, e, l);
    }
}
```

On clicking the legend in getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_meta' of undefined

Tried this also. it didn't work either.

```
var original = Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick;
Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick = function(e, legendItem) {
  /* do custom stuff here */
  original.call(this, e, legendItem);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It almost seems like that the example of the documentation is wrong, seems like they dont give the chart which is why it fails, if you provide the chart yourself and write the full onclick it does work

Example:

```js
const defaultLegendClickHandler = Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick;
var newLegendClickHandler = function(e, legendItem) {
  alert(legendItem.text)
  const index = legendItem.index;


  const {
    type
  } = chart.config;
  if (type === 'pie' || type === 'doughnut') {
    // Pie and doughnut charts only have a single dataset and visibility is per item
    for (i = 0, ilen = (chart.data.datasets || []).length; i < ilen; ++i) {
      meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
      // toggle visibility of index if exists
      if (meta.data[index]) {
        meta.data[index].hidden = !meta.data[index].hidden;
      }
    }
  } else {
    const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
    const ci = this.chart;
    const meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);

    // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
    meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;

    // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
    ci.update();
  }
  chart.update();

};

const options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: '# of Votes2',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: '# of Votes3',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: '# of Votes4',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      onClick: newLegendClickHandler
    }

  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the legend onClick by update the legend using following line.

```
@ViewChild('barChart') barChart: BaseChartDirective;

legend: {
    labels: {
    onClick: (event, barLegendItem, legend) => {
      const datasetIndex = barLegendItem.datasetIndex;
      const scatterDataset = this.barChartData.datasets[datasetIndex - this.noOfInnings];
      const barDataset = this.barChartData.datasets[datasetIndex];
      scatterDataset.hidden = !scatterDataset.hidden;
      barDataset.hidden = !barDataset.hidden;
      legend.chart.update(this.barChart);
    }
  }

HTML :
canvas id="chart1" class="w-100 h-100" baseChart
            #barChart
            [data]="barChartData"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
            [legend]="barChartLegend">
    </canvas>
```